# OnUnhandledKeyEventListener Unknown Error

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am getting this error:

> Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

I have spent hours searching google and just cant find the cause, the thing that is confusing me is that the app runs on APIs earlier than v28.
But crashes without fail on all devices running api 28

> Logcat attached below:

```
07-02 12:59:51.667 18223-18223/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-02 12:59:51.699 18223-18233/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
07-02 12:59:51.752 18223-18223/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-02 12:59:51.775 18223-18223/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
07-02 12:59:52.248 18223-18241/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-02 12:59:52.256 18223-18223/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
07-02 12:59:52.295 18223-18241/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-02 12:59:52.296 18223-18241/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-02 12:59:52.300 18223-18241/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7f42be844b60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
07-02 12:59:52.320 18223-18241/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f42be844b60: ver 2 0
07-02 12:59:52.326 18223-18241/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
07-02 12:59:52.344 18223-18241/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f42be844b60: ver 2 0
07-02 12:59:53.408 18223-18223/freeskate.esk8hub.skatehub I/Choreographer: Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 12:59:51.667 18223-18223/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-02 12:59:51.699 18223-18233/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
07-02 12:59:51.752 18223-18223/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-02 12:59:51.775 18223-18223/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
07-02 12:59:52.248 18223-18241/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-02 12:59:52.256 18223-18223/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
07-02 12:59:52.295 18223-18241/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-02 12:59:52.296 18223-18241/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-02 12:59:52.300 18223-18241/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7f42be844b60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
07-02 12:59:52.320 18223-18241/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f42be844b60: ver 2 0
07-02 12:59:52.326 18223-18241/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
07-02 12:59:52.344 18223-18241/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f42be844b60: ver 2 0
07-02 12:59:53.408 18223-18223/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 13:32:22.589 18223-18233/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
```

I am not using any event listeners as of yet in the application, the only thing listening for clicks is the Navigation drawer, and that is the pre-made activity from Android Studio.

> Below is the Java for handling activity drawer:

```
int id = item.getItemId();

        //Below we will instantiate the fragments into the nav-view. Instead of hiding and showing individual elements manually

        if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
            //Handle login action
            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new Login());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_register) {
            //Handle register action
            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new Register());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Register");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_support) {
            //Handle support action.
            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new Support());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Support");
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
```

> The fragments are handled in the onCreate function

```
//Lets add the fragments to the frame layout in the design file.
fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, new Login());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login");
```

Can anyone see any issues here? I have been trying for hours and can't seem to find the solution.